# Why integral curves cannot be tangent to each other?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am watching Lecture 1 of the differential equation course on MIT OpenCourseWare.
The teacher said, for $y'= f(x,y)$, if $f(x,y)$ is continuous around a point $(x0,y0)$, it would guarantee at least one solution, and if $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial {y}}$  is continuous, it would ensure uniqueness of the solution, i.e. there would be only one integral curve passing through  $(x0,y0)$, meaning two integral curves could not be tangent to each other at $(x0,y0)$.

Can anyone explain why there would be only one integral curve passing through $(x0,y0)$, i.e. two integral curves could not be tangent to each other at $(x0,y0)$, if $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial {y}}$ is continuous at $(x0,y0)$? 
If 2 integral curves are tangent to each other at $(x0,y0)$, then they should have the same derivative at  $(x0,y0)$, which is equal to $f(x0,y0)$, right? How would this make $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial {y}}$ discontinuous at $(x0,y0)$?

Thanks!

Comment: From a point with an imposed derivative, you cannot "fork".

Comment: The teacher said if you forked, then there would be 2 derivatives. But if the two integral curves were tangent to each other, there would still be only 1 derivative at this point. That's partly why I don't understand why two integral curves can not be tangent to each other.

Comment: By what magic could the curves diverge ?

Comment: Why can't it be two solutions? Neither of the 2 curves diverges, and they can still satisfy $y1(x0)=y0, y2(x0)=y0, y1'(x0)=f(x0,y0),  y2'(x0)=f(x0,y0)$

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: That's the lecture I was watching. Starting from 40:21, the teacher drew an example. But I don't understand his explanation. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/lecture-1-the-geometrical-view-of-y-f-x-y/

Comment: What is the example ?

Comment: Doesn't the teacher just say its hard to guess that the partial derivative being continuous is the required condition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The teacher cites the Picard-Lindelöf theorem.
It says that in a neighbourhood of the considered point, the ODE has a solution if $f$ is continuous and that the solution is unique if $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$.

---

By definition $f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$, if there is a constant $L\in \mathbb R$ such that $|f(x,y_1)- f(x,y_2)|\le L|y_1-y_2|$ for all $x,y_1,y_2$.

I will sketch the proof for uniqueness:

Assume there are two solutions $y_1(x), y_2(x)$ which coincide at $x=x_0$.
Then
$$|y_1(x)-y_2(x)|= |\int_{x_0}^x (y_1'(s)-y_2'(s))~ ds|\le\int_{x_0}^x |(f(s,y_1(s))-f(s,y_2(s)))~ds|\\ \le L \int_{x_0}^x |y_1(s)-y_2(s)|~ds.$$
So if we set $z(x):=|y_1(x)-y_2(x)|$, then  $z\le L \int_{x_0}^x z(s) ~ds$.

This can be used to show $z\le 0$. (for example using the Grönwall inequality)
But obviously $z\ge 0$, so $z=0$, but this just means that $y_1(x)=y_2(x)$.
Hence the solution is unique.

---

So why does the prof mention $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}$ should be continuous?

This is because the partial derivative being continuous in s neighbourhood implies that the function is Lipschitz continuous in this neighbourhood.

This is a consequence of the mean value theorem:

$$ |f(x,y_1)- f(x,y_2)|\le \sup_{t\in [0,1]}|\frac{\partial f(x,y_1+t(y_2-y_1))}{\partial y}| \cdot |y_1-y_2|.$$
As we can choose the neighbourhood to be convex, the supremum is finite, (i.e $<\infty$) and takes the role of $L$.

Thus $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in the second variable.

Answer (score 8):

For the differential equation $$y'=3|y|^{2/3}$$ you have (at least) $4$ solutions through the initial point $(x_0,y_0):=(0,0)$, namely $y_1(x)\equiv0$, $\,y_2(x)=x^3$, $\,y_3(x)=\min\{0,x^3\}$, and $\,y_4(x)=\max\{0,x^3\}$, the exact reason being that for the right hand side $f(x,y):=|y|^{2/3}$, while continuous at $(0,0)$, the partial derivative ${\partial f\over\partial y}$ is not even defined there.

Answer (score 3):

If

$f_y(x, y) = \dfrac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y} \tag 1$

is continuous in some neighborhood $U$of $(x_0, y_0)$, then $f(x, y)$ is Lipschitz continuous in $y$ on some, perhaps smaller, open ball $B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon) \subset U$ (we note $(x_0, y_0) \in B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$); this follows from the observation that, since the closure $\bar B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$ of $B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$ is compact and $f_y(x, y)$ is continuous, $\vert f_y(x, y) \vert$ is bounded by some real $L > 0$ on $\bar B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$; then for

$(x, y_1), (x, y_2) \in B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon), \tag 2$

we have

$\vert f(x, y_2) - f(x, y_1) \vert = \left \vert \displaystyle \int_{y_1}^{y_2} f_s(x, s) \; ds \right \vert \le \left \vert \displaystyle \int_{y_1}^{y_2} \vert f_s(x, s) \vert \; ds \right \vert \le \left \vert \displaystyle \int_{y_1}^{y_2} L \; ds \right \vert = L\vert y_2 - y_1 \vert, \tag 3$

which shows that $f(x, y)$ is Lipschitz on $B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$; thus we may invoke the 
[Picard-Lindeloef theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) to affirm that there exists *precisely one* solution passing through any point in $B((x_0, y_0), \epsilon)$; in particular, there is exactly one integral curve $y(x)$ of

$y' = f(x, y) \tag 4$

with

$y(x_0) = y_0. \tag 5$

Thus, "two integral curves could not be tangent to each other at $(x0,y0)$" since there is in fact only *one* integral curve through this point!

Our colleague Christian Blatter has, in his answer, provided some good examples of how uniqueness may fail in the absence of Lipschitz continuity.